# Can I Set Spark Image source in CSS?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4, stylesheet, flex4.5

I want to set image source from stylesheet in flex 4.6.

for Example,

```
<s:Image styleName="imgDelete" />
```

Source will be given in CSS...

How can I do this ???

Answer (score 1):

taken from: [How to set an image's source in a Flex stylesheet (not Embed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059983/how-to-set-an-images-source-in-a-flex-stylesheet-not-embed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
minWidth="636" minHeight="389" width="636" height="389"
>

<fx:Style>
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    s|Application {
        image-source: Embed(source="done.png");
    }

</fx:Style>
<mx:Image source="{getStyle('imageSource')}" >
</mx:Image>
</s:Application>
```